# Grouping reactive input generates empty output-plot

Tags: r, shiny, grouping, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am building a Shiny app to display variables of the "European Social Survey" (table and graph). Therefore I created conditional panels with "selectInput" where the user can select which variable should be displayed. In a second step I want to group the displayed variable by e.g. gender. For doing so I included a checkbox. If this checkbox is TRUE, a further conditional panels shows up where the user can choose the independent variable:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(likert)
library(DT)
library(plotly)


levels.netusoft <- c('Sehr wenig', 'Etwas', 'Stark', 'Sehr stark', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.ppltrst <- c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.polintr <- c('Überhaupt nicht', 'Sehr wenig', 'Etwas', 'Stark', 'Sehr stark', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.psppsgva <- c('Überhaupt nicht fähig', 'Wenig fähig', 'Ziemlich fähig', 'Sehr fähig', 'Vollkommen fähig', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.actrolga <- c('Wenig fähig', 'Ziemlich fähig', 'Sehr fähig', 'Vollkommen fähig', 'Verweigert', 'Weiß nicht', 'Keine Antwort')
levels.gndr <- c('männlich', 'weiblich')
dataset <- data.frame('netusoft'=factor(sample(levels.netusoft[1:7], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'ppltrst'=factor(sample(levels.ppltrst[1:8], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'polintr'=factor(sample(levels.polintr[1:8], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'psppsgva'=factor(sample(levels.psppsgva[1:8], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'actrolga'=factor(sample(levels.actrolga[1:7], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      'gndr'=factor(sample(levels.gndr[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE)),
                      check.names=FALSE)


# ----- UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "European Social Survey Österreich Dashboard", titleWidth = 300),
        dashboardSidebar(width = 300,
                         selectInput(inputId='round', label="Wählen Sie eine ESS Runde aus",  
                                     c("ESS 1" = "1",
                                       "ESS 2" = "2",
                                       "ESS 3" = "3",
                                       "ESS 4" = "4",
                                       "ESS 5" = "5",
                                       "ESS 7" = "7",
                                       "ESS 8" = "8",
                                       "ESS 9" = "9"),
                                     selected = "9", selectize = FALSE), #end selectinput
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.round == '9'",
                             selectInput(inputId='battery', label="Wählen Sie Themenfeld aus",  
                                         c("A: Medien-, Internetnutzung, Soziales Vertrauen" = "A",
                                           "B: Politische Variablen, Immigration" = "B"), selectize = FALSE), #end selectinput
                         ), #end conditionalPanel
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.round == '9' && input.battery == 'A'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "avA_9", label = "Wählen Sie eine Frage aus", 
                                         c("A2|Häufigkeit Internetnutzung" = "netusoft", 
                                           "A4|Vertrauen in Mitmenschen" = "ppltrst"), selectize = FALSE), #end selectInput
                         ), #end conditionalPanel 
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.round == '9' && input.battery == 'B'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "avB_9", label = "Wählen Sie eine Frage aus", 
                                         c("B1|Interesse an Politik" = "polintr", 
                                           "B2|Politische Mitsprachem?glichkeit" = "psppsgva", 
                                           "B3|Fähigkeit politischen Engagements " = "actrolga"), selectize = FALSE) #end selectInput
                         ), #end conditionalPanel
                         checkboxInput(
                             inputId = "group",
                             label = "Daten gruppieren",
                             value = FALSE), #end checkbox
                         
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.group==true",
                             selectInput(
                                 inputId = "UV",
                                 label = "Daten gruppieren nach:",
                                 c("Geschlecht" = "gndr")
                             ) # end conditionalPanel
                         )
                         
        ), # end dashboardSidebar
        
        dashboardBody(
            
            fluidRow(
                box(width = 7, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    title = "Table:",
                    dataTableOutput("tabelle", width = "100%")
                ),
                box(width = 8, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    title = "Graph:",
                    plotOutput("plot", width = "auto", height = 500)
                )
            ) # end fluidRow
            
        ) #end dashboardBody
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    av.select <- reactive({
        if (input$battery == "A" && input$round == "9") {
            av.select <- input$avA_9
        }
        else if (input$battery == "B" && input$round == "9") {
            av.select <- input$avB_9
        }
        return(av.select)
    })
    
    
    #Plotting the data  
    output$plot <- renderPlot(function(){
        reactive({
            data <- subset(dataset, select=c(av.select(), input$UV))
            data <- data[complete.cases(data)==1,] %>%
            mutate_all(as_factor) %>%
            droplevels(exclude = c("Weiß nicht", "Verweigert", "Keine Antwort")) %>%
            as.data.frame() -> plot.data
}) 
        
        
        plot.data.g <- likert(items = plot.data[,1, drop=FALSE], grouping = plot.data[,2,drop=FALSE])
        
        if(input$group==FALSE)
        {plot(plot.data.g) + 
                ggtitle(q_text()) + 
                xlab("Frage")}
        
        if(input$group==TRUE)
        {plot(plot.data.g) + 
                ggtitle(q_text()) + 
                xlab("Frage") + 
                labs(x=av.select()) + 
                facet_grid(input$UV)}
        
    })
    
    #Creating the table
    output$tabelle <- renderDataTable({
        x <- av.select()
        dataset %>%
            count(!!as.symbol(x)) %>%
            mutate(Antwortkategorie=as_factor(!!as.symbol(x))) %>%
            mutate(n=n) %>%
            mutate(Prozent = prop.table(n)) %>%
            mutate('Kum. Prozent' = cumsum(Prozent)) %>%
            as.data.frame() -> for.table
        
        print(for.table)
        
        datatable(for.table[,c(3,2,4,5)], extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(dom = 'Brtip', buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'))) %>%
            formatPercentage(c('Prozent','Kum. Prozent'), 1) 
    })
    
    
}    

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My question/problem is now: How can I generate to group the dependent and independent variable server-side? My code returns an empty plot.

Comment: Don't nest your reactives.  In addition, please provide a *minimal reproducible example*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I updated the code above. Can you please explain, how I can unnest the reactives.

Comment: @Limey, do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I may have time to take another look when you provide a minimal *reproducible* example.  Your code does not provide a MRE at the moment because I don't have access to your `Documents` folder.  In addition, the link you provide takes me to a *list* of posible data files, but I don't know which one you are using.  Ideally, we need to be able to copy and paste the code you provide and end up with a working demonstration of your problem.  Help us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the code above and added a dataset.
I hope this helps you to help me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your definition of `output$plot`.  If you run into this sort of problem in the future, I suggest you break the problem down into smaller steps: start at the beginning - do you have the correct input data?  Then go to the next step: does your summary function work? Etc, etc.

The issues here seem to be:

- You nest reactives.  Don't put a `reactive` definition inside a `renderXXX` call.
- You don't assign your `reactive` inside the `renderPlot` to an object.
- Your `renderPlot` defines a function that is never called.

I don't have the `lickert` package and don't want to install it just to answer a StackOverflow question, so I've modified your `renderPlot` to produce a simple bar chart of the input data, which I suspect is close to what you want.  You'll have to make obvious modifications to restore your original plot.

Replace your current definition of `output$plot` with:

```
    #Plotting the data  
    plot.data <- reactive({
        data <- subset(dataset, select=c(av.select(), input$UV))
        data <- data[complete.cases(data)==1,] %>%
            mutate_all(as_factor) %>%
            droplevels(exclude = c("Weiß nicht", "Verweigert", "Keine Antwort")) %>%
            as.data.frame()
        data
    }) 
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        # plot.data.g <- likert(items = plot.data[,1, drop=FALSE], grouping = plot.data[,2,drop=FALSE])
        # p <- plot(plot.data.g) +  ggtitle(q_text()) + xlab("Frage")
        p <- plot.data() %>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=netusoft))
        if(input$group) {
          p <- p + facet_grid(input$UV)
        }
        p
    })
```

Here's an example of the plot produced with grouping requested.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and advice, Limey!